# Forbid folder1 to import anything from folder2

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, eslint

Is there a simple way to prevent `folder1` to import anything from `folder2` in modern JS?

---

My context is a ReactNative/Expo detached app which somehow contain 2 distinct apps in one (think Uber customer and Uber driver, in a single native app).

I want to make a clear separation of the 2 codebases, and have a shared common folder which both apps can import. Code of one app should never be able to import code of the other app.

I am ok to any valid solution as long as it can make my test script and CI fail. I've looked at `ESLint` but couldn't find anything to do that.

I don't want to use `LernaJS` or `Yarn Workspaces` as symlinks don't yet work reliably on `Metro` bundler and I don't want to try a new packager like `Haul` just for that when simpler solutions might exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eslint-plugin-import plugin has useful rule. Could be what you're looking for: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-restricted-paths.md